# How to split one column into multiple columns by delimiter (with different numbers of delimiter)

Tags: r, dataframe, delimiter

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
continent <- c("Europe", "Asia")
country <- c("France;Germany;Italy", "Japan")
start_problem <- data.frame(continent, country)
start_problem
```

I would like to seperate the values in the column `country` to multiple columns, one for every country. The end product should look like:

```
continent <- c("Europe", "Asia")
country1 <- c("France", "Japan")
country2 <- c("Germany", NA)
country3 <- c("Italy", NA)
goal <- data.frame(continent, country1, country2, country3)
goal
```

Using `separate_wider_delim()` does not work since not every continent has the same amount of countries, thus not the same amount of delimiters in the original column.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first find out how many columns are needed by finding the `max` number of occurrence of the delimiter `;`. Then `paste` that information in the `into =`  parameter of `separate` with the "country" string.

```
library(tidyverse)

col_number <- max(str_count(start_problem$country, ";") + 1)

start_problem %>% separate(country, 
                           into = paste0("country", seq_len(col_number)), 
                           sep = ";")

  continent country1 country2 country3
1    Europe   France  Germany    Italy
2      Asia    Japan     <NA>     <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you Benson for the very quick response. Your solution works great and makes me learn new functions.

Answer (score 2):

Another option by first separating the rows with `separate_rows`. Create a column with the names to use for `pivot_wider` to make your data wider like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
start_problem %>%
  separate_rows(country, sep = ";") %>%
  mutate(col_name = paste0("country", row_number()), .by = continent) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col_name, values_from = country)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   continent country1 country2 country3
#>   <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 Europe    France   Germany  Italy   
#> 2 Asia      Japan    <NA>     <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Quinten, your solution works as well with the added benefit of doing everything in one go.

Comment: This is a nice solution; to slightly improve it you might use this: `start_problem %>%
  separate_rows(country) %>%
  group_by(continent) %>%
  mutate(col_name = str_c("country", row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col_name, values_from = country)`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann how does that improve the solutiin?

Comment: @onyambu compare the two solutions to see how

Comment: Thanks @ChrisRuehlemann, nice use of `str_c`!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann there is no difference. The solution you gave does not improve on the given solution but rather uses an older version of dplyr to do the same. ie you used `group_by`

Comment: @onyambu Then maybe an issue with me using an older dplyr version. The solution I get from the solution as posted by @Qinten is this: `# A tibble: 2 × 6
  continent .by    country1 country2 country3 country4
  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 Europe    Europe France   Germany  Italy    NA      
2 Asia      Asia   NA       NA       NA       Japan `

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann the fact that you have a column `.by` means you are using an older version of `dplyr`. Consider using `dplyr>=1.10` and you will note that using `.by` in your mutate/summarize etc function is just a short form of `group_by`. Also note that we are in version `1.1.1` meaning you are almost 2 generations behind

Answer (score 1):

in Base R:

```
cbind(start_problem[1], read.csv2(text=start_problem[,2], header = FALSE))
  continent     V1      V2    V3
1    Europe France Germany Italy
2      Asia  Japan
```

if you strictly want `NA` then use

```
cbind(start_problem[1], read.csv2(text=start_problem[,2], header = FALSE, na.strings = ''))
  continent     V1      V2    V3
1    Europe France Germany Italy
2      Asia  Japan    <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: Also a good solution, thank you kindly Onyambu!